# Hard drive faulty or not?

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I have a serious problem with the hard drive of my laptop. I was using Windows 10 and few days ago I got a `no bootable device` error. I tried to change some bios settings but nothing changed. Then I turned to my usb stick with live Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. After spending some time with it, I thought it was actually better than Windows; programs run more stable and faster. So, I decided to get rid of Windows and install Ubuntu. Even though I have deleted all the partitions and make a clean install letting Ubuntu to arrange all the partitions I couldn't boot into Ubuntu as well.
When I ran SMART test I get no error. Also fsck gave no error. Disk seem to be healthy but doesn't boot. What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: Can you boot from the live media?

Comment: Yes, that is the only way I can get online.

Comment: OK that was not clear in the question. Anyway I do think you have a dead and or dying hard drive.

Comment: I think the same but I can copy files to the disk without problem. SMART tests and fsck report no error. Don't know which part has failed.

Comment: My personal experience is SMART is not a good or through test. I have replaced many hard drives that SMART says have no issues.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS, and then booting in correct mode to match install? Does this run report? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: When I installed in UEFI mode. I was getting blank screen after selecting Ubuntu on Grub. My last try was installing Ubuntu in legacy mode but this time I got this “attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'” error. Can you tell me what is ppa version?

Comment: Shoud I tick the check box saying “Install third-party software for graphics and Wi-fi hardware..” on the installer?

Comment: I just restarted and this time hallelujah! I don't know how but it has booted now. Hope it doesn't happen again. Thanks for your helps.